# Moving local.xml outside of the public folder

Tags: magento-1.9, setup

I've seen quite a few arguments perpetuating that .htaccess renders the local.xml safe.  You would also need to be sure that proper permissions are in place.  Otherwise with some of the backdoors available, the .htaccess could be rendered useless.  I'm left here to wonder though, why isn't there an easy way to park the local.xml file outside of public_html.

It appears that the directory to local.xml is hardcoded in several files: Security.php, Config.php, Update.php, Notify.php -- to name a few.

Am I overlooking something here? What is the best way to relocate local.xml outside of public_html?

Comment: The main reason that no-one bothers is because there often is nothing in `local.xml` of any value. Sure, it could expose DB credentials, but without public MySQL access, it offers very little. Hacker's primary targets would be accessing the store files themselves, which if they have managed to achieve would mean the location of the `local.xml` file would be irrelevant anyway. On my security checklist, moving `local.xml` would be at the very end.

Comment: At one time before it underwent MageBayVaporation, there was a lonely little how-to for doing that. Not many people seem to have bothered, and nobody saw fit to mirror it to StackExchange. If the attacker has access to your file system, there are more useful things to do, like reflecting all credit card credentials to a remote location.

Comment: Unfortunately, with the nature of backdoors, you don't need public access, but I get both your points.

Comment: If there's a backdoor where no public access is needed, your whole store is already compromised where the "local.xml" file is not very important anymore so I don't think relocating it outside of "public_html" is something necessary lest it breaks stuffs during upgrade or extensions installation.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running PHP via PHP-FPM or FastCGI, it is probably running under an other Linux user than Apache.
You could `chmod 600 app/etc/local.xml` and `chown` it to the user PHP is running under.
This way the file can only be used by PHP, and can not be read via web.